# Moderator inbox splits notices between main and meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, global-inbox

I saw the diamond on the moderator inbox turn blue (on Server Fault) and clicked on it to see what new activity there was. To my surprise, there was absolutely nothing new...

[image]

Until I went to Meta Server Fault, where I saw there was a new question. And also noticed that the moderator inbox there *only* showed meta posts.

[image]

Can these somehow be combined, so that I see both types of notices whether on main or meta?

---

On the main site, I found the meta posts. They are simply being shown at the end of the list, rather than in reverse chronological order mixed in with the mod messages. (Mod messages don't appear at all on meta, presumably because meta would have its own set of mod messages?)

[image]

Comment: Yeah, you should be getting the meta post notifications on the main site along with the mod message notifications, all sorted in reverse chronological order.

Comment: +1 for the red circle... ;) I'm seeing similar behavior on the Pets and Photography sites as well now.

Comment: still tracking down child meta not showing the parent, something crazy there - but the sorting should be good now

Comment: @NickCraver Yes, the messages are now sorted.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know this is busted, but it's broken in a very weird way that's not at all apparent.  First thing in the morning I'll get data locally to set up this test and figure out the cause.  We'll have main and meta matching soon, as intended.  Didn't want to leave you hanging, I am working on it...and I'm sure I'll feel like an idiot when seeing the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now be fixed.

We're in an awkward state right now with regards to network messaging.  Certain messages, especially mod-only messages, are stored at the network level, but now they're consumed only on a specific site (or its child meta site).  We're planning on a big refactor that will sort out how everything is stored, so issues like this should go away (or if they do occur, they'll be much easier to debug).

Thank you for find this!

Comment: Looks fixed to me.